# Cannot see Lightning Web Component in custom section of Page Edit

Tags: unmanaged-package

After following Trailhead instructions, I have been able to install an unmanaged package into Trailhead Playground and confirm that I can add a **Lightning Web Component** to a page (namely the Opportunity page).

However, after doing the exact same steps to install the same package (and promote) in my Developer Org: I cannot see the **Lightning Web Component**

Could you explain why?

Comment: Did you activate my domain ? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/intro_reqs_my_domain.htm

Comment: Thank you! The reason is that I did not roll out to org users :D. Silly newbie me.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. At the bottom of the Components palette, there's link "Deploy your domain". After my own domain is deployed, it must ALSO be **rolled out to users** (the very action that I previously had missed).